# wpf datagrid background color

Tags: wpf, datagrid, background

How to change background color of Left Top Corner of datagrid. I tried to give color to  whole datagrid but still same.

[image]

Thanks

Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That color is the same that's used in the selectedrow background when the datagrid loses focus, so:

```
<Style x:Key="DGStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource SelectedItemBackgroundNotFocused}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: How to do this if I want to give border as well to that

Comment: Which border are you refering to?

Comment: using your code I was able to fill color in that area, but i want to have right and bottom area black border with L1 and Port1

Answer (score 0):

The part that you like to style is a "select all" button in the DataGrid template. If you extract the template using Blend and find the button the rest is a piece of cake!

- Extract Template -open Blend, put DataGrid on MAinWindow, right-click, select Edit Template, Edit Copy, click OK.
- When you done extracting it, go to code behind and in the Extracted datagrid style find:

  ```
  <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" ...
  ```

That's your button! Style it any way you like it :) which I know you can (from looking at your other posts)

- When you done with the style, just copy paste it in your Visual Studio solution, and apply the style to your datagrid